# Error 403 Forbidden -- permissions on apache2, tomcat6, mod_proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy

I'm *not* a complete beginner and sorry for posting an ambiguous question that has been posted in other slightly various forms so numerously. Anyway I get this error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at gookie.localhost Port 80
```

I have apache2 proxying a tomcat6. here are the details:

- the tomcat install is at /home/ae1/lib/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.29
- ln -s /home/ae1/lib/java/apache-tomcat-6.0.29 /var/www/tomcat6
- http.conf:

```
<Directory "/var/www/tomcat6/webapps/springapp">
    Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
            Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

- /etc/hosts has this entry: `127.0.0.1 localhost gookie.localhost`
- /etc/apache2/sites-available/gookie.localhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >
  ServerName gookie.localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/tomcat6/webapps/springapp
  DirectoryIndex index.jsp index.html index.htm index.php

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/springapp
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/springapp
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/home/www/tomcat6/webapps/springapp">
        Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

- the /var/www/tomcat6/conf/server.xml file has:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443"
           proxyName="gookie.localhost"
               />
```

I had `proxyPort="80"` in `server.xml` and still no luck.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: And some more insight: localhost:8080 works okay, and localhost:8080/springapp redirects to gookie.localhost/springapp and gives the same 403 error. without this: `ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/springapp ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/springapp ` I get apache to show index.jsp without parsed <% %> tags at gookie.localhost, but as soon as I add the proxy directives it breaks.

Comment: Okay the solution was to change this file: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.conf to display `<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        ProxyRequests Off

        <Proxy *>
                AddDefaultCharset off
                Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
        </Proxy>
`

Comment: Put it in an answer please, it's really confusing without any line breaks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution is to have this in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        AddDefaultCharset off 
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all 
    </Proxy>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Dude once i was setting up a thing, and it started working after 20 restarts. Go figure.

Answer (score -6):

step1. You need to open file name “phpmyadmin.conf”. this is the phpmyadmin configuraiton file.
where you need to replce the code.

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Replace code

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
```

Step2. 
Now you need to open another file file is you Apache **“httpd.conf”** file.
This is also your Apache configuration file.
You may find this file under “C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\”
This path is again depend on the installation directory of you wamp server.
Under this file you need to change the code.
**First search this code “# onlineoffline tag – don’t remove”**
You probable found this code in the mid of the file.
And then **remove “Allow from 127.0.0.1″ and replace “Deny from all” with Allow from all”**
And yes if possible create some unique password for your “phpmyadmin” so this will not accessible for outsider (ignore if you are using local machine).

Comment: (a) The OP is not on a Windows machine. (b) He is not using PHP, but Tomcat, which is Java based. (c) He's trying to configure `mod_proxy` which you don't even mention (d) You have multiple typos.